# attach a list with jquery to a dom element

Tags: jquery, json

I expect to recieve a json containing a list of url-s by a jQuery.getJSON() call, when I mouse over a div with a specific class.

I want to somehow attach the json's data to the div and later on I want to access those urls by javascript.

How can I attach and access a list of data to a dom element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach data to a dom element with the [jQuery data API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

```
$("#someDiv").data("url", "http://www.example.com");

// ...

var url = $("#someDiv").data("url");
```

Edit: you can attach any data you want ...

```
// where urls is the list returned from your service
$("#someDiv").data("urls", urls);

// ...

var urls = $("#someDiv").data("urls");
var oneUrl = urls[0];
```

Comment: the problem is that it is only 1 url and I want to attach a list